# Recursive relation, how to calculate the period of repeating pattern

Tags: recursive-algorithms

The qualification round of the [Facebook Hacker Cup](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup) was held last weekend, and in the last problem you had to calculate the values of a vector according to this recursive relation (for some given values of a, b, c and r):

$m(0) = a\\
m(i) = (b \cdot m(i - 1) + c) \bmod r$

After programming a trivial solution for the problem I could see there was a pattern. For instance, for this test case:

```
a: 6, b: 30, c: 524, r: 98
```

The vector was:

```
[[18, 84, 6, 18, 84, 6, 18, 84, 6,...
```

How can I calculate the period of the pattern? (Do not worry, the qualif. round ended and this won't give me additional points or anything, it's just out of curiosity ;)

Comment: From a programming point of view or analytically? For programming you could simply check whether a resulting number already occured and the distance to the iteration where it occured would be the period.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\displaystyle m(n) = \left( b^n a + c\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{b^j}\right) \mod r$. If $a$ occurs again as $m(n)$, then 
$$
b^n a + c\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{b^j} \equiv a \mod r
$$
$$
(ab+c-a)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{b^j} \equiv 0 \mod r
$$

Let $q = r/gcd(r,ab+c-a)$. Then you need $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{b^j} \equiv 0 \mod q$. So, if you look at the sequence $1,1+b,1+b+b^2,\ldots$ modulo $r$, the period is given by the period in this sequence. The repetition need not always start with the first element.

Comment: Then note that $\frac{b^{n + 1} - 1}{b - 1} = 1 + b + b^2 + \cdots + b^n$, and if $\gcd(q, b - 1) = 1$ this is 0 only when $b^{n + 1} - 1 = 0 \pmod{q}$, so you are interested in the order of $b$ modulo $q$.

Comment: This is essentially how linear congruential random number generators work, and the definitive study of those is in Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming", volume 2.